# How to upload two images in same react form in formik and yup not multiple images

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am new to React. I have one form with three images, form works perfectly with one image but when try to upload image in second box with same code it took the first image. I did copy and Paste the first image upload code for second box. now the problem is when I try to upload image in second box same image also get uploaded in first box. here is what I have tried so far

```
import "./influencerPersonalInfo.css";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import AddBoxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddBox";
import { personalValidation } from "../../../../validation/Validation";
import { ErrorMessage, Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import HeaderNinfo from "../../HeaderNinfo";
import {ImagePreview,ImagePreviewTwo} from "../../ImagePreview";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";




const InfluencerPersonalInfo = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null)
  const fileRefOne = useRef(null)
  const fileRefTwo = useRef(null)

  const fileHandler = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0])
}
  const defaultValue = {
    fullName: "",
    stageName: "",
    gender: "",
    languages: "",
    location: "",
    description: "",
    file:null,
    
  };
 

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log({
      values
  
  });
}

  return (

          <div className="row">
            <Formik
              initialValues={defaultValue}
              validationSchema={personalValidation}
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
              {({ values, setFieldValue }) => (
                <Form>

                    <div className="col-xxl-6 col-lg-7 col-md-10">
                    <h3 className="mb-2">Profile Photo*</h3>
                    <p className="mb-3">Add at least 3 Photo to continue</p>

                    <div className="row profile-img">
                      <div className="col-xxl-4 col-lg-4 col-6  mb-4">
                      <div className="img-show">
                      {values.file && <ImagePreview file={values.file} />}
                          <div className="cancelbtn" id="cancelbtn">
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-rectangle-xmark fs-3"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div className="icons">
                            <p>{values.file ? "" : "No File chosen"}</p>
                          </div>
                         
                            <input
                              accept="image/*"
                              ref={fileRefOne}
                              hidden
                              multiple
                              
                              type="file"
                              onChange={(event)=>{
                                
setFieldValue("file",event.currentTarget.files[0]);
                              }}
                            
                            />
                           
                            <span className="btn-upload" >
                            
                              <AddBoxIcon  onClick={()=>{
                                fileRefOne.current.click();
                              }}></AddBoxIcon>
                           
                          </span>
                        </div>
                       
                        <span className="text-danger">
                          <ErrorMessage name="file" />
                        </span>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-xxl-4 col-lg-4 col-6  mb-4">
                        <div className="img-show">
                          {values.file && <ImagePreview file={values.file} />}
                          <div className="cancelbtn" id="cancelbtn">
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-rectangle-xmark fs-3"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div className="icons">
                            <p>{values.file ? "" : "No File chosen"}</p>
                          </div>
                         
                            <input
                              accept="image/*"
                              ref={fileRefTwo}
                              hidden
                              
                              
                              type="file"
                              onChange={(event)=>{
                                setFieldValue("file", ...event.currentTarget.files[0]);
                              }}
                            />
                           
                            <span className="btn-upload" >
                            
                              <AddBoxIcon  onClick={()=>{
                                fileRefTwo.current.click();
                              }}></AddBoxIcon>
                           
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        
                        <span className="text-danger">
                          <ErrorMessage name="file" />
                        </span>
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-xxl-4 col-lg-4 col-6  mb-4">
                        <div className="img-show">
                          <img src="" alt="" className="img-fluid" />
                          <div className="cancelbtn" id="cancelbtn">
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-rectangle-xmark fs-3"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div className="icons">
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-cloud-arrow-up"></i>
                            <p>No File chosen</p>
                          </div>
                          <button className="btn-upload">
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="file" className="default-btn" hidden />
                      </div>

                      <div className="col-xxl-4 col-lg-4 col-6  mb-4">
                        <div className="img-show">
                          <img src="" alt="" className="img-fluid" />
                          <div className="cancelbtn" id="cancelbtn">
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-rectangle-xmark fs-3"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div className="icons">
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-cloud-arrow-up"></i>
                            <p>No File chosen</p>
                          </div>
                          <button className="btn-upload">
                            <i className="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="file" className="default-btn" hidden />
                      </div>
                       <div className="text-end mt-5">
                    <button className="btn-form" type="submit">
                      Continue
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </Form>
              )}
            </Formik>
          </div>
)
          
export default InfluencerPersonalInfo;
```

validation code

```
const SUPPORTED_FORMATS = ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]

export const personalValidation = yup.object().shape({
    fullName: yup.string().required('Full name is required').nullable(),
    stageName: yup.string().required('Stage Name is required'),
    gender:yup.string().required('Gender is required'),
    languages:yup.array().min(1).required('Select atleast one language'),
    location:yup.string().required('Location is required'),
    description:yup.string().required('Location is required'),
    file:yup.mixed().nullable().required('This picture is required').test(
        "FILE_SIZE",
        "Uploaded file is too big",
        (value)=>!value||(value && value.size<=1024*1024)
    ).test(
        "FILE_FORMAT",
        "Uploaded file has unsupported format",
        (value)=>!value||(value && SUPPORTED_FORMATS.includes(value?.type))
    )
})
```

ImagePreview code

```
import React,{ useState } from "react";


export const ImagePreview = ({file}) => {
    const [preview, setPreview] = React.useState(null);
   
    const renderOne = new FileReader();
    renderOne.readAsDataURL(file);
    renderOne.onload = ()=>{
        setPreview(renderOne.result);
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <img src={preview} alt="preview" className="img-fluid" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: when upload first image second box automatically catch the first image]

Comment: You have defined `file` as a single field. Try defining `imageOne` , `imageTwo` and so on.... also name the `<input/>` and `validationSchema` accordingly.

If this is your case then avoid `multiple` in the `<input/>` fileds